# PostgreSQL drop relationship

Tags: postgresql

How can I drop relationship between tables?

I've multiple tables which are related to each other. My objective is the export data from each table with Insert query such that when I import it, it shouldn't  ask me for a relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ALTER TABLE .. DROP CONSTRAINT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html)

`ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT fk_constraint_name`

You can find the constraint name from the [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html) table

`SELECT conname FROM pg_constraint co JOIN pg_class cl ON co.conrelid = cl.oid WHERE contype = 'f' AND relname = 'mytable'`

Comment: So there are many constraints in each table that are related to other tables. Can I achieve it at once?

Comment: You need one DROP CONSTRAINT for every constraint you want to drop